# How to resize Holoviz-Panel application to mobile phone screen

Tags: python, holoviz-panel

I have deployed a panel web application with my hugging space account, and it appears nicely on my monitor. Although the app would be aimed at users accessing the application though a mobile phone. I would like to adjust font,widget dataframe and plotsizes for mobile display.

I was running through Holoviz Panel documentation but I couldn't find an easy way. I am now trying the resizing of individual elements manually but the problem is that I have multiple overlayed plots, markdown panel objects and embedded dataframes that I would need to adjust one by one and I have no way to check their new size unless I save and rebuild the app in hugging space and check it on my phone screen every time I change a parameter. I tried setting up sizing_mode, but this would apply to panel objects with plots but e.g. Markdown objects won't change size. Is there a way to enlarge objects synchronously? Is there a "simple" mobile frontend to panel applications?

Comment: I have managed resizingof various objects many thanks to Panel holoviz documentation on their webpage. Still, I have an issue when I load the application on iphone. When compared to the notebook screen appearance (I use windows 10) several plots dislocate. When I try visualizing the app on my notebook with the inspect functionality of my browser it runs the app nicely. Could it be because of different operating systems?